# Get value from object with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a problem when get a value from object. I need get a value that your key is a value from other Object.

[Captura 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOnBS.png)

[Captura 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy6b6.png)

But in Typescript display this error.

[Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fZyW.png)

It's possible to get the value without modifying the object type?

```js
public data: string | {};
```

Comment: Please post code as code! Don't post code as screenshot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `typeof` - it will return `string` or `object`. If it returns object you can then use key syntax, otherwise the value will be the variable you can use directly.

```
s = 'jeremy'
o = {'s':'gordon'}
a = [s,o]
console.log(typeof(a[0])) // string
console.log(typeof(a[1])) //object
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with cast to any.

const data: any = this.row.data;

```js
  
  ...
  mounted() {
    this.row.columns.forEach(element => {
      if (element.show === this.headerMobile) {
        this.titleLabel = element.label;
        const data: any = this.row.data;
        this.titleLabelValue = data[element.show];
      }
    });
  }
  ...
```

Thx @JGFMK